# Intersect SurfaceEllipse with another NASA Worldwind

Tags: java, osgi, worldwind

I have here an Renderable Layer with a bunch of SurfaceEllipses on it.
Now I want to intersect each ellipse with all of the other.

As far as i know, there isn't such a method in WorldWind. 
But, is there any way to get the intersection of the borders?

Talking about NASA WorldWind

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sad Answer: not possible. Sigh.

Answer (score 1):

AbstractSurfaceShape objects have assessor methods for their Sector objects.
Sectors have several different comparison methods including intersects.

A Sector comparison of your SurfaceEllipses will get you a great first pass.
After that ray intersects can get you the point of intersection.